# Sensenet: Export Contents

Tags: sensenet

I'm trying to export content from sensenet using (http://wiki.sensenet.com/Export#Configuration)

"export" command call:
Export.exe -SOURCE /Root/Sites/Test -TARGET C:\ExportSensenet -ASM ..\bin
I also tried without the "ASM" parameter.

```
Export did not complete successfully.
Export ends with error:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SenseNet.ContentRe
pository.Storage.SR' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLo
adException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the Loa
derExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.TypeHandler.GetTypesByInterface(Type in
terfaceType) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\St
orage\TypeHandler.cs:line 209
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.SR..cctor() in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PAC
KAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Storage\SR.cs:line 22
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.SR.get_ResourceManager()
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Caching.Dependency.CacheDependencyFacto
ry.CreateNodeDataDependency(NodeData nodeData) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECo
mmunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Storage\Caching\CacheDependencyFactory.cs:line 7
5
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.DataBackingStore.CacheNodeData(NodeData
 nodeData, String cacheKey) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Sou
rce\SenseNet\Storage\DataBackingStore.cs:line 325
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.DataBackingStore.GetNodeData(NodeHead h
ead, Int32 versionId) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\Se
nseNet\Storage\DataBackingStore.cs:line 212
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Node.LoadNode(NodeHead head, VersionNum
ber version) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\St
orage\Node.cs:line 1644
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.User.get_Administrator() in c:\Builds\8\SenseNe
t\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\User.cs:line 38
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Security.DesktopAccessProvider.get_CurrentUser(
) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentReposi
tory\Security\DesktopAccessProvider.cs:line 36
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Security.AccessProvider.ChangeToSystemA
ccount() in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Storag
e\Security\AccessProvider.cs:line 72
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Security.DesktopAccessProvider.GetCurrentUser()
 in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentReposit
ory\Security\DesktopAccessProvider.cs:line 52
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Security.AccessProvider.ChangeToSystemA
ccount() in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Storag
e\Security\AccessProvider.cs:line 72
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.DoStart() in c:\Builds\8\Sen
seNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\RepositoryInsta
nce.cs:line 144
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.Start(RepositoryStartSetting
s settings) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Con
tentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:line 108
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Repository.Start(RepositoryStartSettings settin
gs) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepo
sitory\Repository.cs:line 58
   at SenseNet.Tools.ContentExporter.Exporter.Main(String[] args) in c:\Builds\8
\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Export\Exporter.cs:line
 139
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.SR.get_ResourceManager()
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Caching.Dependency.CacheDependencyFacto
ry.CreateNodeDataDependency(NodeData nodeData) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECo
mmunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Storage\Caching\CacheDependencyFactory.cs:line 7
5
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.DataBackingStore.CacheNodeData(NodeData
 nodeData, String cacheKey) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Sou
rce\SenseNet\Storage\DataBackingStore.cs:line 325
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.DataBackingStore.GetNodeData(NodeHead h
ead, Int32 versionId) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\Se
nseNet\Storage\DataBackingStore.cs:line 212
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Node.LoadNode(NodeHead head, VersionNum
ber version) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\St
orage\Node.cs:line 1644
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.User.get_Administrator() in c:\Builds\8\SenseNe
t\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\User.cs:line 38
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Security.DesktopAccessProvider.get_CurrentUser(
) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentReposi
tory\Security\DesktopAccessProvider.cs:line 36
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Security.AccessProvider.ChangeToSystemA
ccount() in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Storag
e\Security\AccessProvider.cs:line 72
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Security.DesktopAccessProvider.GetCurrentUser()
 in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentReposit
ory\Security\DesktopAccessProvider.cs:line 52
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Security.AccessProvider.ChangeToSystemA
ccount() in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Storag
e\Security\AccessProvider.cs:line 72
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.DoStart() in c:\Builds\8\Sen
seNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\RepositoryInsta
nce.cs:line 144
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.Start(RepositoryStartSetting
s settings) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Con
tentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:line 108
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Repository.Start(RepositoryStartSettings settin
gs) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepo
sitory\Repository.cs:line 58
   at SenseNet.Tools.ContentExporter.Exporter.Main(String[] args) in c:\Builds\8
\SenseNet\PACKAGECommunity\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Export\Exporter.cs:line
 139
```

I did not change the export.exe.config file and it has the right database configuration.

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown? A nullref? Pls add the first line, above the stack trace.

Comment: I'm running this through command line. I updated the error message above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is a sign of a missing library. First I'd try to simply copy all the libraries from the web\bin folder to the web\Tools folder (where you execute the tool). If that does not help, pls make sure that the runtime bindings in the export config are the same as in the web.config.

Comment: Got it! I copied the libraries from "bin" to "Tools" folder. Thank you.